# What went wrong with my piecewise linear equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A stock price goes

- from US 10 to US 12 from January 1st to January 31,
- from US 12 to US 9 from February 1st to February 28th,
- from US 9 to US 15 from March 1st to March 31st

And the graph looks like this:

[image]

After I find out each function, I got these results.

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &=\phantom{-}\frac1{15}x+10 \\[4pt]
g(x) &=-\frac19x+12 \\[4pt]
h(x) &=\phantom{-}\frac15x+9
\end{align}$$

After I sketch on graph, the results turn out as expected.

$$\begin{align}
f(x) &=\phantom{-}\frac1{15}x+10\qquad\{\;1\leq x\leq31\} \\
g(x) &=-\frac19x+12\qquad\{31\leq x\leq59\}\\
h(x) &=\phantom{-}\frac15x+9\qquad\{59\leq x\leq90\}
\end{align}$$

[image]

What went wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're assuming that the first number in each section (i.e. $10$, then $12$, then $9$) are the $y$-intercepts, i.e. occur when $x = 0$. This is not the case!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3737284/edit) to explain how you got your functions ... or at least one of them. (Don't explain in comments. They're easily overlooked.) It's pretty clear that you aren't making the proper accommodation for the starting $x$-value in each interval, but showing your work will help us help you in identifying the exact flaw in your thinking.

Answer (score 2):

As stated before, you cannot reset $x$ to zero. Moreover, the functions do have wrong coefficients. Let
$$ f(x) = mx+n \, .$$
Now we can find the coefficients $m$ and $n$ by inserting values of $x$ of which we know the function values. Hence, for $f(x)$  we get
$$ f(x=0) = n = 10 \quad \text{and} \quad f(x=31) = 12 = m 31 + 10 \Rightarrow m= \frac{2}{31}  \, , $$
which gives
$$ f(x) =  \frac{2}{31} x + 10 \, .$$
The other functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are obtained analogously.

Answer (score 1):

When calculating each piecewise part of the curve, you reset $x$ to 0. But x represents days from the beginning, so you will have to subtract the cumulative days till the month previous to get the number of days within the particular month you are analysing. For eg, in the second function, replace $x$ with $(x-31)$